# Can't get @PreAuthorize to work with role hierarchies

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a custom authentication provider that's returning a concrete implementation of 'AbstractAuthenticationToken`with`ROLE_ADMIN`only.  I have a method annotated with`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`.  I'm trying to set up a role hierarchy to give my admin user access to this method.

I have the following in my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="roleHierarchy" class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
        <beans:value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="methodExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy" />
</beans:bean>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>
```

The request to the protected method gets denied, although it works if I change the annotation to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`.

I put a breakpoint on the `AccessDeniedException`, which was being thrown from `AffirmativeBased.decide(...)`.  The issue appears to be that the `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter`'s `expressionHandler` is `null`.  That suggests to me that there's something wrong in my wiring up of my roleHierarchy or methodExpressionHandler.

I there anything obviously wrong with my spring-security.xml?  Is there something I'm misunderstanding about how this stuff should be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh how silly of me...  There's not enough context in my question to answer this, but I've resolved it.

I had `<global-method-security>` in both my `spring-security.xml` and my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.  I was only making changes within spring-security.

The give-away was when I put a break point on `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`'s constructor.  It was being called twice.  One was having `setRoleHierarchy` called, the other wasn't.

The solution was:

1. move the common role hierarchy definition out to a separate file to be imported by both `spring-security.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.
2. Move `<global-method-security>` and the `methodExpressionHandler` bean from `spring-security.xml` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Comment: I also have same problem. I tried you solution but is not working . One more thing why you are including RoleHierarchy bean in  spring-security.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml. Can not we have whole configuraion in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject `roleHierarhy` into `roleVoter`. Example from the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#authz-hierarchical-roles):

```
<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>
<bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF
            ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: No luck.  The PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter's expressionHandler is still null, and the second voter in the accessDecisionManager is just a plain-old RoleVoter.  I'll try explicitly defining the accessDecisionManager, but I'm sure I've been down this road before.